# Solving Limit with Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The equation:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{\sin(x)(e^x-1)}
$$

Any tip on how to solve this?
For denominator, I am trying to plug in the value $−2x$ and $x$ in pre-computed series of $e^x$. I have to calculate the limit using Taylor series.
Any help is appreciated, I am confused on how to progress.

Comment: Why are you plugging in $-2x$?

Comment: I was taught that way in class through an example. Can you suggest a better way of solving?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the Taylor series gives approximations to the function.

We have $$1-\cos x=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots=\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)\text{ as }x\to0$$

Similarly, $$\sin x = x+O(x^3)\\e^x-1=x+O(x^2)$$

Therefore $$\begin{align}\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin(x)(e^x-1)}
&=\frac{x^2/2+O(x^4)}{(x+O(x^3))(x+O(x^2)}\\
&=\frac{x^2/2+O(x^4)}{x^2+O(x^3)}\to\frac12\text{ as }x\to0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh I had the wrong idea of how to solve this. Thank you for clearing it up, I appreciate it

Comment: @lizzie21 You are welcome.  If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark so that it leaves the unsolved queue.

Answer (score 0):

We have the Taylor development of the functions around the point x = 0

$cos(x) \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}, sin(x) \approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}, e^x \approx 1+x$

So

$$ \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{1-cos(x)}{sin(x)(e^x-1)}=\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\frac{x^2}{2}  }{ (x-\frac{x^3}{6})x  } = \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{3}{6-x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$